# Delete Multiple Selected Items in ListView (cab) in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I want to delete multiple selected items (row) in my listview (Gmail style).
If I select (with longClick) a row, nothing happens.
I've found this code on internet, and i've tried to insert it in my project.

MainActivity

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container,
            false);

    Lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Lista);
    items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    items = GetLists.GetRecordList(rootView.getContext());
    adapter = new ListaAdapter(rootView.getContext(),
            R.layout.list_view_item, items);
    Lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    Lista.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
    Lista.setChoiceMode(Lista.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menu) {
    switch (menu.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                ListViewItem selectedItem = adapter.getItem(selected
                        .keyAt(i));
                adapter.remove(selectedItem);
            }
        }
        actionMode.finish();
        return true;

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
    adapter.removeSelection();

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position,
        long arg2, boolean arg3) {
    final int checkedOut = Lista.getCheckedItemCount();
    actionMode.setTitle(checkedOut + " selezionato");
    adapter.toggleSelection(position);

}
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class ListaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ListViewItem> items;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public ListaAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<ListViewItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TitoloPrincipale);
        holder.txtSubTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.Sottotitolo);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ListViewItem list = getItem(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(list.getNomeFarmaco());
    holder.txtSubTitle.setText(list.getFasceOrarie());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(list.getIcon());
    // convertView
    // .setBackgroundColor(mSelectedItemsIds.get(position)
    // : Color.TRANSPARENT);
    return convertView;

}

public void remove(ListViewItem item) {
    items.remove(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedCount() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
```

have you got any idea?
tks

Comment: is delete menu is displayed when you long click on an item? Im about go to bed, plz answer quickly!!! Maybe I got your problem

Comment: I go to bed now, I leaved the answer, plz check it.

Comment: no. nothing "new menu" and nothing background for the selected raw

Comment: your means the menu (provide deleting option) is not displayed when you long press item?

Comment: I updated the whole source code, please check again.

Comment: doesen't work yet. it never change raw selected background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code has nothing to do with long-clicks. The only occurrence of "long" is for a `long` parameter to a method. :-)

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/LongPress) demonstrates an action mode starting up based upon a long-click of a list row. The key is `onItemLongClick()`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

    return(true);
  }
```

Here (courtesy of registering the activity as the `OnItemLongClickListener` for the `ListView`), we toggle on `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` and check the item that was long-clicked, thereby activating the action mode.

Comment: i've modified my method but doesn't work.

`
Lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int position, long arg3) {
    Lista.setChoiceMode(Lista.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    Lista.setItemChecked(position, true);
    return false;
   }
  });
`

Comment: @Anto: I suggest that you download the project, or at least the one class file (a single activity) and try running it. See what is different about it from what your code has.

Comment: is possibile, in your opinion, that doesn't work because i use a fragment?

Comment: @Anto: I doubt that your use of a fragment has anything to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem you have not setMultiChoiceModeListener for listview like below
(Plz, see carefully onCreateActionMode and the loop in onActionItemClicked)

```
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);


            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.mnDelete:
                        SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                        for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
                            items.remove(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mode.finish();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: i've only tried to select. if I click (longclick) the raw, the selection doesen't work

Comment: I still not understand what you want and your context. Ussualy, when a user long press on a item, a menu (with delete option) is displayed, then user select "delete" on menu, item will be deleted. Which step where you are?

Comment: the first step. I want to select one or more raw but the selected raw background don't change and the menu isn't displayed

Answer (score 0):

I've solved.  thank you all.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container,
            false);

    Lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Lista);
    items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    items = GetLists.GetRecordList(rootView.getContext());
    adapter = new ListaAdapter(rootView.getContext(),
            R.layout.list_view_item, items);
    Lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    Lista.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
    Lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
    switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                ListViewItem selecteditem = adapter.getItem(selected
                        .keyAt(i));
                adapter.remove(selecteditem);
            }
        }
        // Close CAB
        arg0.finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
    arg0.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, arg1);
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
    adapter.removeSelection();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode arg0, int arg1, long arg2,
        boolean arg3) {

    final int checkedCount = Lista.getCheckedItemCount();
    arg0.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
    adapter.toggleSelection(arg1);
}
```

}

Comment: I know your problem at Lista.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this); and return true in onCreateActionMode. However, I cannot understand what you explain so nobody cant help you. Try to explain better.